# OneNote API intermittently returns HTTP 400 when querying O365 SharePoint SiteId

Tags: sharepoint-online, onenote-api

My code calls the OneNote API to resolve a SharePoint Online site URL to a SiteCollectionId and SiteId. We get a bearer token, set the HTTP auth header and issue a GET request to:

```
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/myorganization/sitecollections/FromUrl(url='https://mytenantxyz.sharepoint.com/sites/copynotesite')
```

For approx a week, it has been returning the expected response, similar to:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://www.onenote.com:576/api/v1.0/$metadata#Microsoft.OneNote.Api.SiteMetadata",
  "siteCollectionId": "111e03ac-468c-4a28-9aab-543098ef49bb",
  "siteId": "555d72a0-f82f-4e4c-ae8a-17ef0ea04f32"
}
```

However, today it has decided to return the following in approx 9 out of 10 requests:

```
{
  error":  {
     "code" : “20158”,
     "message": "Unable to get SiteMetadta for the url specified in the request.",
    "@api.url": "http://aka.ms/onenote-errors#C20158"
    }
}
```

The Microsoft docs ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn750990.aspx)) explain error 20158 as:
"*Unable to get metadata for the site URL specified in the request. Check the format of the supplied URL. Supported formats include https://domain.sharepoint.com/site-a and https://domain.com/sites/site-a. (SharePoint support is in Preview.)*"
I was unaware that this was in preview any more (I thought it was GA), but anyway it doesn't explain why it intermittently works for exactly the same input (same URL and bearer token).

Could it just be a bug in the OneNote API or SharePoint API that it must call under the covers?

Comment: Would you mind providing us with the value of the X-CorrelationId HTTP header for one of the requests that failed with 400?

Comment: The failures have stopped occurring for now - suspect a software update may have been made on the API, which left it broken for ~24 hours. We are now capturing the X-CorrelationId headers in our error logs, so we can investigate/escalate if it happens again.

Comment: Trawling our trace logs, I can see it is still happening but less frequently than previously. Here's an example X-CorrelationId: 16504d70-a8ff-48af-a59b-e50e61a97f14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the blog - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2015/06/11/and-sharepoint-makes-three.aspx

We added the FromUrl method so you can pass in an absolute site URL and get the site collection and site IDs. You should make this call only when needed, and then store the values (site collection and site IDs) for future use in your requests to the OneNote API.

this however does not answer intermittency. Please share the X-correlationId header with us for a failing request so that we can help further.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Sharad. We have modified our code to store the Site/SiteCollectionIds so that we don't make the FromUrl call as regularly. However this doesn't really answer the question, it just provides a mitigation.